# Convert SQL Server timestamps to MySQL time stamps

Tags: timestamp

I exported a database from SQL Server. It had a column of type `timestamp` which is giving me value something like `39635.74541924769`.

How can I convert it into simple date format on MySQL?

I am trying to display it on a website using PHP. Previous database was linked to the site with ASP.NET and SQL Server.

I want to convert this timestamp from `39635.74541924769` to something like `2012-09-25 10:15:23`

or some other readable format.

Thanx in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server `timestamp` datatype has **nothing** to do with date and/or time.

It's just a sequential counter, typically used to detect rows that have changed since being read.

Newer versions of SQL Server now call it `ROWVERSION` - which is really what it is.

There's **no date and/or time** contained in that data! You cannot convert it to a proper date.